# Requisição API da ANEEL utilizando Macros do EXCEL [ VBA ]

Tags: api, microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Escrevi essa função com objetivo de criar uma requisição a API da ANEEL em uma Macro usando VBA :

```
Sub ConsultarAPI()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim concessionaria As String
    Dim grupoTarifarico As String
    
    ' Obtenha o nome da concessionária da célula desejada
    concessionaria = Sheets("Inicio").Range("B21").Value
    
    ' Obtenha o grupo tarifário
    grupoTarifarico = Sheets("Inicio").Range("B27").Value
    
    'Obtenha o grupo tarifário
    classTarifaria = Sheets("Inicio").Range("B19").Value
    
    ' Obtenha o valor da célula B20 como o filtro para a subclasse
    Dim filtroSubClasse As String
    filtroSubClasse = Sheets("Inicio").Range("B20").Value
    
    ' Substitua os espaços em branco por %20 na string da concessionária
    concessionaria = Replace(concessionaria, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Substitua os espaços em branco por %20 na string do grupo tarifário
    grupoTarifarico = Replace(grupoTarifarico, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Substitua os espaços em branco por %20 na string da classe (DscClasse)
    classTarifaria = Replace(classTarifaria, " ", "%20")
    
  ' Substitua os espaços em branco por %20 na string da subclasse
    filtroSubClasse = Replace(filtroSubClasse, " ", "%20")

    
  ' Adicione um filtro para o campo DscSubClasse na URL
    Dim filtroDscSubClasse As String
    filtroDscSubClasse = "%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27" & filtroSubClasse & "%27"
    
    ' Adicione um filtro para o campo DscModalidadeTarifaria na URL
    Dim filtroDscModalidadeTarifaria As String
    filtroDscModalidadeTarifaria = "%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27"
 
  ' Adicione o filtro para o campo NomPostoTarifario na URL
    url = "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27" & concessionaria & "%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27" & grupoTarifarico & "%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27" & classTarifaria & "%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27" & filtroSubClasse & "%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201"

    ' Salvar os detalhes da requisição antes de fazer a solicitação GET
    SalvarDetalhesRequisicao url

    ' Inicialize o objeto xmlhttp
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Faça a solicitação GET para a API
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    ' Verifique o status da resposta da API
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        ' Faça o parsing do JSON retornado
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.responseText)

        ' Verifique se o campo "success" é verdadeiro
        If json("success") = True Then
            ' A consulta foi bem-sucedida, obtenha o resultado
            Dim records As Object
            Set records = json("result")("records")

            ' Verifique se existem registros retornados
            If records.Count > 0 Then
                ' Obtenha o registro mais recente
                Dim record As Object
                Set record = records(1)

                ' Acesse os campos e atribua os valores às células do Excel conforme necessário
                
                Sheets("Inicio").Range("B23").Value = record("DscREH")
                Sheets("Inicio").Range("B24").Value = record("DatInicioVigencia")
                Sheets("Inicio").Range("B25").Value = record("DatFimVigencia")
                
                
                Sheets("Inicio").Range("B28").Value = record("VlrTUSD")
                Sheets("Inicio").Range("B29").Value = record("VlrTE")
                
                ' ...
                ' Atribua outros campos e células conforme necessário
            Else
                MsgBox "Nenhum registro encontrado."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "A consulta falhou: " & json("error")
        End If
    Else
        ' A solicitação falhou, exiba a mensagem de erro
        MsgBox "Falha na requisição à API! Status: " & xmlhttp.Status & " Resposta: " & xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
    
    ' Libere o objeto xmlhttp
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Essa macro está escrevendo a requinte requisição :

[https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27Equatorial%20AL%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27B3%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27Não%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27Não%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201](https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27Equatorial%20AL%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27B3%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201)

Ao testar a requisição em um navegador, consigo verificar que ela está funcionando como imaginei trazendo esse retorno :

```
{
"help": "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search_sql",
"success": true,

"result": {
"sql": "SELECT * FROM "fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4" WHERE "SigAgente" = 'Equatorial AL' AND "DscSubGrupo" = 'B3' AND "DscClasse" = 'Não se aplica' AND "SigAgenteAcessante" IN ('NA', 'Não se aplica') AND "DscBaseTarifaria" = 'Tarifa de Aplicação' AND "DscSubClasse" = 'Não se aplica' AND "DscModalidadeTarifaria" = 'Convencional' AND "NomPostoTarifario" = 'Não se aplica' ORDER BY "DatInicioVigencia" DESC LIMIT 1",

"records": [

{
"_id": 221157,
"_full_text": "'-02':22 '-05':3,18,21 '-06':2 '-28':19 '12272084000100':16 '19':47 '2023':1,13,17 '2024':20 '24':9 '3.203':7 '304':46 '561':44 '83':45 'al':15 'aplica':30,33,36,39,43 'aplicação':25 'b3':26 'convencion':27 'de':8,10,12,24 'equatori':14 'homologatória':5 'maio':11 'mwh':40 'nº':6 'não':28,31,34,37,41 'resolução':4 'se':29,32,35,38,42 'tarifa':23",
"DatGeracaoConjuntoDados": "2023-06-05",
"DscREH": "RESOLUÇÃO HOMOLOGATÓRIA Nº 3.203, DE 24 DE MAIO DE 2023",
"SigAgente": "Equatorial AL",
"NumCNPJDistribuidora": "12272084000100",
"DatInicioVigencia": "2023-05-28",
"DatFimVigencia": "2024-05-02",
"DscBaseTarifaria": "Tarifa de Aplicação",
"DscSubGrupo": "B3",

"DscModalidadeTarifaria": "Convencional",
"DscClasse": "Não se aplica",
"DscSubClasse": "Não se aplica",
"DscDetalhe": "Não se aplica",
"NomPostoTarifario": "Não se aplica",
"DscUnidadeTerciaria": "MWh",
"SigAgenteAcessante": "Não se aplica",
"VlrTUSD": "561,83",
"VlrTE": "304,19"
}
],

"fields": [

{
"id": "_id",
"type": "int4"
},

{
"id": "_full_text",
"type": "tsvector"
},

{
"id": "DatGeracaoConjuntoDados",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscREH",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "SigAgente",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "NumCNPJDistribuidora",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DatInicioVigencia",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DatFimVigencia",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscBaseTarifaria",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscSubGrupo",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscModalidadeTarifaria",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscClasse",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscSubClasse",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscDetalhe",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "NomPostoTarifario",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "DscUnidadeTerciaria",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "SigAgenteAcessante",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "VlrTUSD",
"type": "text"
},

{
"id": "VlrTE",
"type": "text"
}
]
}
}
$.theater[*].movies
```

Agora quando tento usar a macro no excel por meio da macro estou recebendo essa mensagem :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway </title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
       <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
     </center>
       <hr>
     <center>nginx/1.18.0(Ubuntu)
     </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

O que está gerando essa mensagem ? Como posso corrigir isso ?

Comment: Perguntas que dependem de URLs externos e voláteis não são adequadas para este site. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, convertendo o código em um [mcve], que automaticamente a pergunta é destacada para uma reavaliação. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Comment: O sistema já alertou que a conversa ficou extensa, então foi [movida para um chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146517/discussion-on-question-by-mateus-de-la-fuente-cezar-requisicao-api-da-aneel-util); Quem tiver interesse em ler ou acrescentar algo pode usar o link fornecido.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não descobri o motivo exato mas creio que o `XMLHTTP` teria que definir algum cabeçalho de requisição para ser aceito a requisição no servidor de destino, como por exemplo o `host` que é adicionado em tempo de requisição.

Porém é possível você resolver isso usando outro cliente para requisição, o `Microsoft WinHTTP Services`, com ele sua requisição seria algo assim:

```vb
    Dim url As String
    Dim client As WinHttpRequest
    
    url = "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27Equatorial%20AL%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27B3%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27Não%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27Não%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201"
    Set client = New WinHttpRequest

    client.Open "GET", requestURL, False
    client.send
```

Caso não queira adicionar o `Microsoft WinHTTP Services` como referência (que eu sugiro adicionar para ativar o Intellisense), pode só criá-lo assim:

```vb
Set client = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```